# Server lease roll. Need to change all existing direct links?

Tags: redirect

My server is leased, and the lease is expiring soon. Do I need to change all of the direct links on the existing server to point to the new server or can I use some kind of redirect? I'm a real newbie at this.

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Please provide more detail on your environment

Answer (score 1):

You need to migrate your environment from the old server to the new one.

Implementation of this advice is left up to the reader (or the reader's sysadmin) -- Nobody here knows your environment, so we can't tell you with any certainty what is required or involved.